# My GUI renders differntly on one of the computers I run it on

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a .Net application that was originally created in Visual Studio Professional 2005, using the .Net 2.0 framework.

Recently, I have opened the project in Visual C# Express 2010, made some minor changes, and built it using .Net framework 4.0.

Everything works like a charm except for one quite annoying part. When I am running the application on a HP EliteBook 8740w, with a 1920x1200 screen, a group of GUI controls get shuffled around, so that they land on top of eachother. This error does not show up when running on my Windows 7 64 bit workstation with external display of 1900x1080 resolution. Neither does it show when running on a Windows XP laptop with 1024x768 resolution.

I have tried to connect a 1600x1200 external display to the EliteBook, but the error shows up there also.

The controls that get messed up are a set of comboboxes, numericUpAndDowns, and labels, laid out in a table layout container, that in turn is placed on a tab page in a tab page control.

I have tried creating a new tab page control and table layout container from scratch, and then moving the comboboxes etc into the new table layout container, but the error prevails.

I would really appreciate some help in this matter, because I don't know what else to try. I am starting to suspect that there is something wrong with the graphics on the EliteBook, but, then again, everything else renders nicely on its screen.

Thanks,
Fredrik Israelsson

--- Edit ---

Thank you for your quick answers. Before I had a chance to look at them, I think I solved the problem by myself. Stumbled upon a thread about why Visual Studio automatically changes sizes of controls although one has set anchor and dock properties to None. One of the answers mentioned the AutoScaleMode property. I changed AutoScaleMode from Font to None on my main application Window, and no the GUI renders nicely on all my computers.

Thanks again!

/Fredrik Israelsson

Comment: Hey Fredrik, make sure to accept an answer, or if none were really quite right post and accept an answer yourself!

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that this is because the two machines have different DPI settings. This is always a pain with Windows Forms.

Here are a few links that might help.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605.aspx

http://www.sellsbrothers.com/writing/winformsAutoScaling.htm

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to Hardware Acceleration. Is your application a WinForms or a WPF one?
I have faced really odd behaviors when using VS2010 on Win7 64 bit only because it was trying to use Hardware Acceleration when I built the app.

Improving Performance by Changing the Visual Experience
You might have a problem with Hardware Acceleration in VS2010. I had an issue with rendering applications built using WPF because of this.

Give it a try: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/06/22/improving-performance-by-changing-the-visual-experience-vstipenv0017.aspx

And if that doesn't fix your issue, go to your video card settings (nvidia or amd catalyst) and do a "reset settings" on the computer where the app doesn't correctly paint itself. Then try again.